# bug in nested arrays in a url get string

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, url, querystringparameter

Basically I want the query string `?foo%5B%5Bbar%5D%5D=whizbang` to give me a result that looks like this:

```
{ 'foo' : { '[bar]' : 'whizbang' } }
```

I'm using rails at the moment, and instead of '[bar]' i'm getting 'bar' (ie the [] stripped out). I tried this in PHP for a comparison, which has '[bar' (rstripped of ]) this seems wrong to me also.

I am trying to work out if this is a bug that i need to log for rails.

I'm using JQuery.ajax to send an object that looks like that to rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to formulate the params in javascript and have access to jquery, you can use `$.param`:

```
$.param({ 'foo' : { '[bar]' : 'whizbang' } })
// => foo%5B%5Bbar%5D%5D=whizbang
```

Comment: Found this "Note: Because there is no universally agreed-upon specification for param strings, it is not possible to encode complex data structures using this method in a manner that works ideally across all languages supporting such input. Until such time that there is, the $.param method will remain in its current form."
in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/" so yes this seems like the way to do this seems strange though